# NetLogo: set initial turtles number with empty neighbors around?

Tags: netlogo

I ask patches sprout a number of turtles equal to slider initial-population on interface, now i wont that each turtle has neighbors around empty and that each patch contain one turtle. Below my wrong-code

```
to setup-turtles

  set-default-shape turtles "circle"
  ask n-of initial-population patches with [(pcolor = white - 1) and (not any? other turtles-here) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors)] [
    sprout-normals 1 [       
        set color blue
        set size 1        
    ]
  ]

end
```

but no result neighbors empty foreach turtle..why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is really what you are asking because the sentence "that each turtle has neighbors around empty and that each patch contain one turtle" is really hard to understand, but here is my guess:

You want turtles to appear only on patches where they will not have any neighbors. But it doesn't work because *at the time* you select your patches, *every single patch* fulfills the criteria `(not any? other turtles-here) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors)`. As soon as you start sprouting turtles, that condition is not true for every patch anymore, but that fact is not taken into account by your code because you have *already* asked the patches to sprout turtles.

What you need to do is to check for the condition again each time you add a turtle. You can do that using [`repeat`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#repeat) and then [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) instead of `n-of`:

```
  repeat initial-population [
    ask one-of patches with [(pcolor = white - 1) and (not any? other turtles-here) and (not any? turtles-on neighbors)] [
      sprout-normals 1 [       
        set color blue
        set size 1        
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: If this runs fast enough for your needs, great. If you find it's too  slow, you might need a bit different algorithm, one that doesn't involve iterating over all of the patches every time a turtle is placed.